# Copying c++ struct in c#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

i'm working with C# and visual studio 2012.

I have a program that recieves a c++ struct with data from tcp socket. In c++ program this struct is serialized, packed and sended in a byte array.

The c++ struct has inheritance, so in first step i thought that using c# classes should be better, reading data with `BitConverter.ToSomething` but the problem comes with c++ padding, i know that visual c++ alignment is 8-byte, so knowing the type and the order of data i could arbitrary jump padding, but i'm trying to do this in a more automatically mode (easier user maintenance and not calculate again if the struct is changed).

Then, i suppose the correct way is change c# classes to structs and duplicate data fields, so the question is: is there anyway to copy []byte to struct regardless of the padding? i saw different examples about how to copy to struct, but in all of them field offset and field size are arbitrary defined with perfect alignment.

i.e:

i'm recieving 80 bytes, 76 is my real struct size, so 4 bytes are padding to memory alignment, but i want the compiler to populate the c# struct knowing that if i recieve an integer and after that a double (i know the order and size of the fields), then there is where 4 extra bytes are put and they have not to be read. Like when you do the same in c++ using pointer to data.

Comment: Don't you have the code of serialize which is used for your recieved data? Usually, serialize routine uses information of classes for serializing object to serial data. You may be able to deserialize the data by reading code of serialize. Goog luck!

Comment: See [Marshal.PtrToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ca6d5z7.aspx). If you really mean *copying*, then how about serializing/deserializing structure to pass in between?

Comment: The alignment and padding rules are exactly the same in C#, the default value for StructLayout.Pack is 8.  Pretty unclear to me how you got in trouble but if you are *intentionally* not emitting the final 4 bytes of padding in the C++ then you'll certainly have headache converting the struct in C#.  Don't do that, use sizeof() in your C++ code.  And verify that you get the exact same size back in C# with Marshal.SizeOf().  If you don't then your struct declaration is not a match.

Comment: Thanks for replies, you are right, after reading a bit more and think about it, i took the way you suggested, Marshal.SizeOf to verify match between structs and HandleAllocs with PtrToStructure for copying data. Now that is converted to C# is easier to deal with it for next steps than try to do it first.